# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/star-off.png"): in rails4 , heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, assets

I made a rails web app and when I deployed it to heroku, everything worked fine locally but online I had those errors:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/star-off.png"):
```

I looked in the answers for similar questions here and I changed this in my production.rb:

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

and I made a rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

but in vain. What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Please follow this steps Ref: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

Answer (score 0):

Try this

add `rails_12factor` gem into your gemfile [github link of gem](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor)

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

install bundle in terminal

```
bundle install
```

stage your changes to github

```
git add .
```

commit your changes to github

```
git commit -a -m "your commit message"
git push
```

push this changes to heroku

```
git push heroku
```

and you are done!

Cheers!

Comment: thank you but I have already done all those instructions and I still have the problem

Comment: Please show your code in which you are trying to load this image `star-off.png`.